# Unveiling a fluid-width header image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to unveil a responsive background image. Basically, I have a value on load. Let's say 50%. So I want half of my image to be sharp, and the other half to be blurred.

Never done this before so I had the idea to produce two images : one plain, one blurred.

HTML - Two empty divs. Those divs are in a container-fluid div, so their width change at every window resize, that's important.

```
<div class="col-lg-9 left-header">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 right-header">
  // some stuff
</div>
```

Now, everything else has to be js and css.
So I start to style my divs accordingly.
Blurred bg, notice absolute positionning :

```
.overlay {
    background:url('../img/overlay.jpg');
    height:580px;
    width:100%;
    background-position:right;
    background-size:cover;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Non-blurred bg

```
.bg {
    background:url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:right;
    height:580px;
}
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yqdx9vgc/, there is a big problem especially at large widths. Indeed, I wanted to play with the width parameter of the .overlay. But then, the two background cover images aren't of the same proportions, so the effect is not working.

Ideally, in the end, I want to set the width with jquery. For instance, if my value is 50%, then I tell jquery to put .overlay at 50% width. But my solution isn't working, how could I keep the same dimensions for both background images with different div sizes ? **While keeping the responsive effect**

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this effect with pure CSS, enjoy:

https://jsfiddle.net/fk9rbgv5/1/

Here is the code:

```css
.unveil-container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-image:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpapers-hd-8000-8331-hd-wallpapers.jpg');
    padding:0;
    /* This is for keeping proportion - remove if you do not want */
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
/* this whole before is for proportion */
 .unveil-container::before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
.overlay {
    background:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpapers-hd-8000-8331-hd-wallpapers.jpg');
    height:100%;
    /* PLAY WITH WIDTH */
    width:50%;
    top:0;
    background-position:100% 0;
    background-size:200% 100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.bg {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 50%;
    background:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpapers-hd-8000-8331-hd-wallpapers.jpg');
    background-size:200% 100%;
    background-position:0%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-9 left-header unveil-container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 right-header">// some stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set 2 elements, one inside the other, and then translate them in opposite directions using translate.

Animating them is easy with javascript.

With this layout, the elements are 100% width, and the background can be cover (or contains)

```js
var target1, target2, step;

function move ()  {
 target1.style.transform = "translateX(" + step + "%)";
 target2.style.transform = "translateX(-" + step + "%)";
 step -= 1;
 if (step < 0) step = 100;
}
function start ()  {
 target1 = document.getElementById('moving');
 target2 = target1.children[0];
 step = 50;
 
    setInterval(move, 20); 
}
```

```css
.base {
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top; 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpapers-hd-8000-8331-hd-wallpapers.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top; 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateX(50%);    
}

.overlayimage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top; 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpapers-hd-8000-8331-hd-wallpapers.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);   
    -webkit-filter: invert();   
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="overlay" id="moving">
<div class="overlayimage">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="start();">start</button>
```

I changed your filter to make it more visible   ...